# How can users with the role of "Author" be allowed to publish a user-defined type of records and that only the author can read the records?

Tags: php, wordpress

please forgive me, I use Google Translite.
The essence of the question is as follows:

How in WordPress for users of the role of "Author" to give the opportunity to publish only a certain type of records, for example, with the slug "refbek", and that after publication of the record only the author could read them, and only after entering the site?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your custom post type (I assume this is what you mean by 'certain type of record? - it helps if you use wordpress terminology so we know what it is you are trying to do and do not have to guess), then define the capabilities eg: edit_custom_post_type https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Add those capabilities to the author post_type. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap
remove whatever capabilities you do NOT want the author to have. (eg: edit_posts) https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap

The wordpress private posts functionality will let them create posts (custom posts etc) that only they can see. https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content.  If you only want them to be able to create private posts, not general ones, then give the edit private custom post type capability https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_private_posts, not edit_posts  (or edit_custom_posts)